# Step line in range selector with Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using a step-line graph with [highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) but i'm having trouble having a step line range selector. You can see an exemple in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hhresek7/).

My graph is like i want it to be : step line. However i tried to use `step : true` in range selector or even `plotOptions` but that doesn't work. I don't find anything in the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector) for it neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a step parameter, also for navigator serie.

```
navigator: {
            series:{
                type:'line',
                step: true
            }
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hhresek7/1/